# Registering IHostedService on a different service provider

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

Is it possible to run an IHostedService on a service provider that is *not* the one provided by `ConfigureServices`?

I am working on a library that helps configure various environments and each one has its own context (the environment context is driven by service providers). I can call `.AddHostedService<>();` just fine, it doesn't throw, but the service constructor never gets called and the service doesn't start.

Edit:

I can manually kick off the services like Andy suggests in the answers, but where would that happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All `IHostedService` implementations are executed by the `IWebHost` that holds on to the `IServiceProvider` which is passed in to `ConfigureServices`.

The `internal` [`WebHost`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/f1b0157a111bab8497c1e04241a18f1a60086d5a/src/Hosting/Hosting/src/Internal/WebHost.cs#L33) object holds on to an `internal` [`HostedServiceExecutor`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/f1b0157a111bab8497c1e04241a18f1a60086d5a/src/Hosting/Hosting/src/Internal/HostedServiceExecutor.cs#L13) that is responsible for instantiating and running `IHostedService` objects.

Since you are running outside of the `WebHost`, you are the one responsible for instantiating, starting and stopping the services.

What you would have to do is emulate what `HostedServiceExecutor` does: Instantiate then iterate all services that implement `IHostedService` and finally call `StartAsync` and `StopAsync`

For example:

```
var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
serviceCollection.AddHostedService<TestHostedService>();
var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

// this will instantiate the services
var myHostedServices = serviceProvider.GetService<IEnumerable<IHostedService>>();
// or: var myHostedServices = serviceProvider.GetServices<IHostedService>();

// start the services up
foreach (var hostedService in myHostedServices)
{
    await hostedService.StartAsync(token);
}

// ...

// Shutting down: stop the services
foreach (var hostedService in myHostedServices)
{
    await hostedService.StopAsync(token);
}
```

This is extremely simplified code. No exception handling is done. This is just to give you the gist of how you'd do it. You should really study `HostedServiceExecutor`'s code.

Comment: thanks this is helpful. I still have a few problems to tackle here though, I will edit the question

Comment: I edited it. Thanks in advance for any other insight you could provide.

Comment: @xandermonkey -- There simply isn't enough context around what you are trying to do to warrant a good answer. Questions on Stack Overflow usually pertain to one subject and they don't change over time. This question states *Registering IHostedService on a different service provider* -- This answer is geared to that problem and it should stay that way. What you should do is work this (or the other answer's) code in to your solution, then start a new question, but this time thoroughly explain what the next steps are.

Comment: thanks, I'm aware. Another question in this case would just add confusion.

Comment: I agree the first point in my addition is not ideal. The second point really is just a response to your answer, which is appropriate. I've removed the first one.

Comment: @xandermonkey -- you'd have to put a better description up of what you are trying to accomplish. I really don't understand the end goal... or even the beginning.

Comment: Sure. In a nutshell, there's a library that configures an instance of a service to target multiple environments. e.g., the production instance can field production requests, or requests for any lower environment. Simply put, the way this library works is by rigging up service providers for each environment that an instance targets.

Comment: The problem here comes in because I need a hosted service running in each target environment, and the hosted service needs to have injected the various services that belong to that target environment. However, the hosted service doesn't run because it's added to the target environment specific service collection.

Comment: Hence me trying to kick off hosted services belonging to the "not provided by `ConfigureServices`" service provider when the application starts up. I understand your solution, but after tinkering around with it I'm not sure where your logic would actually be able to take place.

Comment: I hope that covers it enough. I get that from where you're standing it may seem opaque, doing the best I can to explain it. If your answer is "I don't know because it's just not clear", that is fair and I'll definitely still accept this answer for the explanation of the raw original question at hand.

Comment: @xandermonkey -- Honestly, not trying to sound snarky or anything, but this sounds like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Why would you do it like that? Why wouldn't you just have the service that's using your library just inject your service in to their pipeline? Or have the service call a method in your library (passing in the Service Provider) that will inject everything that is needed?

Comment: I solved this, in case you're curious what I pretty much did was I registered one hosted service that gets the instance configurations injected into it, from there that hosted service kicks off all the other hosted services for each environment on the instance

Comment: In short, I found a home for your solution. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

As alternative to Andy's suggested solution, you can make the `IHostedService` into an adapter that forward the call to its own private `IServiceProvider`:

```cs
public class IsolatedHostedService : IHostedService
{
    private IServiceProvider provider;

    // Functions as Composition Root
    public IsolatedHostedService()
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddXXX();
        provider = services.BuildServiceProvider(validateScopes: true);
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken t)
    {
        provider.GetRequiredService<YourStuff>().DoSomething();
    }
}
```